# Update Manager not starting

Tags: update-manager

I get this after the Update Manager said "Check your Internet Connection"

```
W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  502  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
, W:Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  502  Bad Request [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I can now access the Update Manager, thanks for the answer anyway(didn't try it!)--I do not know the reason but it got fixed. How can I mark this as CLOSE

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
sudo mv lists lists.backup
sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Do you know what you are suggesting?

Comment: i am suggesting him to take a backup of his existing repo list and, remove orignal one and then take an update. was I wrong somewhere ?

Comment: You should explain your answer instead of just leaving a lump of commands.

Comment: oooh, really sorry for that, i thought person asking question is expecting a solution so made it quick, thanks for your suggestion.